# Removing from middle of the linked list c++

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

i have a problem with my RemoveMid function in my linked list.. the code seems ok and there's no syntax error, but when i call this function, the program stops working.. i think there's something wrong with the logic of the function. i hope you may help me to correct it.
this is the implementation of the RemoveMid function

```
template<typename T>
bool LinkedList<T>::RemoveMid(T& target)
{
    Node<T> *current = new Node<T>;
    bool found = false;
    current = start;
    while(current != NULL && !found)
    {
        if(current->next->info == target)
            found = true;
        if(!found)
            current = current->next;
    }
    if(found)
    {
        Node<T> *Ptr;
        Ptr = current->next;
        current = current->next;
        delete Ptr;
        return true;
    }
    else
        cout<<"target not found\n";

}
```

Comment: The description of the function seems to imply that you want to remove something: why are you allocating a new node? Especially, as you are dropping the allocated memory on the ground rather fast creating a memory leak.

Comment: Have you stepped through your test case with a debugger?

Comment: It looks as if you want to use the old trick of maintaining a pointer to the pointer to the element so you can deal with both the pointer to the head and a pointer to the next node. In that case you need to use `&start` and to update it you'd use `&current->next`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this is a Singly Linked List (that is, it only goes forward) since you do not have a Previous pointer.  With that in mind:

```
template<typename T> bool LinkedList<T>::Remove(T& target) // name changed as removing from anywhere in a linked list is effectively the same
{
    Node<T>* current = start; // your allocation caused a memory leak here
    Node<T>* previous = NULL;
    bool found = false;
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        if (current->info == target) // you should be looking at the current node, not the next node
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }

        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    if (found)
    {
        if (previous == NULL)  // deleting head node
        {
            start = current->next;
        }
        else
        {
            previous->next = current->next;
        }

        delete current;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"target not found\n";
    }

    return found;
}
```

Comment: A lot of useless lines here. Found for example. If nothing is found current->next will give NULL. You should use that to your advantage. Look at my code below to see what I mean. Also there is no need to play around with previous current->next->next is a trick that works best with linked lists. :)

Comment: @Void:  I left his code largely in tact (hence a lot of lines I would not use otherwise).  `current->next->next` is not a "trick", it is a logical fallacy.  If you are checking `current`, you cannot assume that `current->next` is non-NULL.

Comment: The code is wrong! If the first element is being deleted, the list is left in an inconsistent state because the `start` now points to a deleted node! (actually, it also dereferences `previous` which is null if the found element is the first element) The way to fix the problem is in my comment above: do not use pointer to the node but use a pointer to the pointer of the node. Otherwise you need special treatment for deleting the first node.

Comment: @Deitmar:  Updated to be more complete.  And having a pointer to a pointer to a pointer is rather overkill, especially when you still need to handle the head node slightly different.

Comment: @ZacHowland: That's the point: You _don't_ need to treat is separately when you do as I see (see my response).

Answer (score 1):

Here is properly working version (I think; I haven't tested it, though, and in my experience untested software is buggy) which seems to resemble the original intent (i.e., no special case when removing the first element):

```
template<typename T>
bool LinkedList<T>::RemoveMid(T const& target)
{
    for (Node<T> **current(&this->start); *current; current = &(*current)->next) {
        if ((*current)->info == target) {
            std::auto_ptr<Node<T>> tmp(*current);
            *current = (*current)->next;
            return true;
        }
    }
    std::cout<<"target not found\n";
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Bare in mind that this is almost certainly a homework assignment meant to convey the needed operations of a linked list.  Though this is clever.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few probs with this code:

1. You're checking the `next` node in your linked list here `if(current->next->info == target)` this will miss your `start` node.
2. You assign `new Node<T>` to your `current` pointer and then reassigning `start` to it two lines latter.
3. You then incorrectly delete the `next` node to the one you found with `Ptr = current->next;` followed two lines later with `delete Ptr`.
4. In between those lines you assign to the node you wanted to remove a pointer to the node you are about to `delete`!

There're probably more errors but fixing all these is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several places I don't understand

```
      Node<T> *current = new Node<T>;
```

Why you want to allocate a new Node to current since current will be assigned to start anyway?

Secondly,

```
    if(current->next->info == target)
        found = true;
```

Why you use `current->next` instead of `current`?  And `current->next` could be NULL which makes `current->next->info` invalid.

BTW, why don't you use the linked list provided by STL?

Comment: The answer to that last question is likely because it is a homework assignment.

Comment: current->next->info cant be invalid because of "while(current != NULL)"

Comment: @Void:  `current->next` can be invalid when `current` is non-NULL.  If `current` is the last item in the list, `next` points to null, therefore there is no `next->info`.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your error:
this assignment `current = current->next;` should be `current->next = current->next->next;` Because if you delete the node that is after your current node you want your current node (`current->next`) to point at the node that is after the one you delete (`current->next->next`)

Also there might be some problem with the code. First of all `current->next->info` will crash your  program if the Node is still not found and `current->next` is `NULL` (`current` points to the last element), obviously in this case `current->next->info` would be illegal. Also you might concerning adding `return false;` after the `cout`

Answer (score -2):

Here is a better version of your code. Less variables and all. Try it and see if it works now. :)

```
template<typename T>
bool LinkedList<T>::RemoveMid(T& target)
{
    Node<T> *current = new Node<T>;
    current = start;
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        if(current->next->info == target)
            break; //stops while loop = faster since the whole list doesnt have to be parsed once we found the target

        current = current->next;
    }

    if(current!=NULL)
    {
        current->next = current->next->next; //we "unlinked" target from the list and linked the rest of list instead
        return true;
    }
    else
        cout<<"target not found\n";
}
```

Comment: You are allocating a new node in your first line (memory leak).  You are also skipping the first item entirely.  Finally, if `current` is the last item in the list, `current->next` is null, and thus, `current->next->next` won't work.